# Rounding to one decimal place using Math.round on an ArrayList.get

Tags: java, formatting, rounding

I have read many posts on `Math.round` and `DecimalFormat` etc. However I dont know how id go about correctly using either of the above within code where its more complicated than just simply declared variables.

```
 List<Float> depthCopy = new ArrayList<>(depthAdd);

        ...//collection sort
        ...//iterate i over arraylist

      if (depthCopy.get(i).equals(depthAdd.get(depthAdd.size() - 1))) {
          System.out.println("Wettest year: " + (1000 + i) + " "
                  + //FORMAT HERE?(depthAdd.get(depthAdd.size() - 1)));
            }
        }
```

This returns a value of: `Wettest year: 2002  1146.3999`

`1146.3999` is correct

however I need to print this value formatted/rounded to 1 decimal place i.e:
`1146.4`

I have tried the following:

```
System.out.println("Wettest year: " + (1930 + i) + " "
                    + (double)Math.round(depthAdd.get(depthAdd.size() - 1)));
```

It returns `1146.0` (incorrect)

Printed value im looking to get is `1146.4`. What is the best way to achieve this? Why would this way be better than other alternatives?

SOLUTION: Instead of Math.round use DecimalFormat

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####.#");
              System.out.println("Wettest year: " + (1000 + i) + " "
                      + df.format((depthAdd.get(depthAdd.size() - 1)));
```

---

Comment: Duplicate? I have explained why this is not a duplicate. There are many threads on simple variables:

`double num = 540.512`
`double sum = 1978.8`

where you would so something like the following to resolve:
`double total = (double) Math.round((num / sum * 100) * 10) / 10;`
OR
`double total = Math.round((num / sum * 100) * 10) / 10.0;`

Comment: Did you try 'Math.round(f * 10.0f) / 10.0f)' (where 'f' is your float)?

Comment: how could I use that though^ given this: `(depthAdd.get(depthAdd.size() - 1)));` is what gives me my value in the first place?

Comment: Look at DecimalFormat

Comment: @Abbie: (depthAdd.get(depthAdd.size() - 1))) gives you the float, right? Assign it to a local variable and use that reference in the calculation. Or am I missing something?